# Prove that any continuous bijection $f:X \rightarrow Y$ from a compact space $X$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

> Prove that any continuous bijection $f:X \rightarrow Y$ from a compact space $X$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$ is a homeomorphism

Requirements for a homeomorphism  $f:X \rightarrow Y$:

1. $f$ is continuous
2. $f$ is bijective
3. $f^{-1}$ is continuous

The first two properties are given in the question, so we just need to show that the inverse is continuous.

So $f^{-1}(Y)$ is the preimage of a Hausdorff space to a compact space. Why is this continuous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A continuous bijection from a compact space to a $T_2$ space is always a homeomorphism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256917/a-continuous-bijection-from-a-compact-space-to-a-t-2-space-is-always-a-homeomo)

Answer (score 4):

Since the $f$ is continuous and bijective, it is a homeomorphism if and only if it is closed. But closed subset of a compact space are compact, image of compact is compact, and compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed.

Comment: thank you. I was wondering why does it have to be closed?

Comment: Homeomorphism are closed. Conversely, a continuous, closed and bijective function is a homeomorphism because, if $A\subseteq X$ is closed, then by bijectivity $[f^{-1}]^{-1}(A)$ (a.k.a. the pre-image of set $A$ under the function $f^{-1}$) is $f(A)$ (a.k.a. the image of $A$ under the function $f$). That's a set-theoretical fact. But $f(A)$ is closed by hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** That map is open that means that image of an open set is open.