# If $A$ is compact and If the graph of a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is compact, then $f$ is continuous.**

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Professor Brian has explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231883) that **If $A$ is compact and if the graph of a function $f: A \subseteq \Bbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is compact, then $f$ is continuous.**

The solution goes like this:

> Suppose that $f$ is not continuous. Then there are a point $x\in A$ and a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $A$ converging to $x$ such that $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge to $f(x)$. Let $G$ be the graph of $f$. Then $\big\langle\langle x_n,f(x_n)\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\big\rangle$ is a sequence in the compact metric space $G$, so it has a convergent subsequence $\big\langle\langle x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k})\rangle:k\in\Bbb N\big\rangle$.

$1.$ Show that the limit of this subsequence must be of the form $\langle x,\alpha\rangle$ for some $\alpha\in\Bbb R$. (Recall that $x$ is the limit of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.)

$2.$ Show that $\alpha\ne f(x)$. Conclude that $\langle x,\alpha\rangle\notin G$. This contradicts the compactness of $G$; how?

**I have trouble proving that $\alpha \ne f(x).$ Here's my attempt: Suppose $\alpha =f(x)$. Then, although the sequence $f(x_i)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ but there exists a sub-sequence $f(x_{n_k})$ which converges to $f(x)$**. **But, Why is this a contradiction?**

Thank you!

Comment: What is $A$ exactly?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Sorry, A is compact

Comment: You do not need to assume that $A$ is compact (although it follows that it is), only that it is Hausdorff (this is not true if $A$ is not Hausdorff, even if it is compact, or even finite). You do not need to assume that $f$ is real-valued, either. To see this, take any closed $F$ in the codomain and note that $f^{-1}[F]$ is the projection onto $X$ of the intersection of the graph of $f$ and $X\times F$, which is compact, as a closed subset of a compact set.

Answer (score 2):

Choose a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $A$ with $a_n\to a$. We show $f(a_n)\to f(a)$.

Now, $G(f)=\{(x,f(x):x\in A\}$ is compact. So, the sequence $\{(a_n,f(a_n)\}\subseteq G(f)$ has a convergent subsequence, say $\big\{\big(a_{n_k},f(a_{n_k})\big)\}\to (x,f(x))\in G(f)$.

Now, $\pi_2:G(f)\to \Bbb R$ defined by $(x,f(x))\mapsto f(x)$ is continuous, so that $f(a_{n_k})=\pi_2\big(a_{n_k},f(a_{n_k})\big)\to \pi_2(x,f(x))=f(x)$.

Similarly, $\pi_1:G(f)\to A$ defined by $(x,f(x))\mapsto x$ is continuous, so that $a_{n_k}=\pi_1\big(a_{n_k},f(a_{n_k})\big)\to \pi_1(x,f(x))=x$. But, $a_{n}\to a\implies a_{n_k}\to a$, and assuming $A$ is Hausdorff we have $a=x$.

Hence, $f(a)=f(x)$. So what we have shown is that for every sequence $\{a_n\}\to a$ we have a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $f(a_{n_k})\to f(a)$.

Now, if possible let $f(a_n)$ doesn't converge to $f(a)$. That means we will find a subsequence $\{f(a_{n_k})\}$ and $\epsilon>0$ with $|f(a_{n_k})-f(a)|\geq \epsilon$ for all $k$. But using similar argument we have a further subsequence $\{f(a_{n_{k_l}})\}$ such that $f(a_{n_{k_l}})\to f(a)$, a contradiction to the fact
$|f(a_{n_k})-f(a)|\geq \epsilon$ for all $k$. So, we are done.

Comment: Why must $\big\{\big(a_{n_k},f(a_{n_k})\big)\}\to (x,f(x))$ I mean, why should the sub-sequence $f(a_{n_k})$ converge to $f(x)$?

Comment: As $\pi_2$ is continuous.

Comment: Projection maps are always continuous.

Comment: To prove this let $\pi:X\times Y\to Y$ be the projection map i.e. $\pi(x,y)=y$. Now, for any open set $V$ in $Y$ we have $\pi^{-1}(V)=X\times V$, which is open in $X\times Y$.